# React naitve animation

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, react-native-animatable

1:I want to fill the image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVhRK.png) with blue color animation inside the image jus like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiO1W.png) how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-masked-view](https://github.com/react-native-masked-view/masked-view)